# Error while add migration to create database in Entity Framework 6, method not found CoreTypeMappingParameters

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to run add migration to create database on my local machine, in the last seconds I get this error:

> Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.

Here is my `Program.cs` :

[image: program.cs]

I have no idea where to look, any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have the correct version of the command line tools installed? Or are you mixing versions?

Comment: @ErikEJ how can i find its version?

Comment: having the same problem, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem based on the video in this article

[click here](https://www.geekinsta.com/mysql-with-net-core-and-entity-framework/)

[image]

the solution is to make all the packages have the same version as `Palemo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql = 6.0.1` .

This made it work and create the migration for Mysql.

Comment: Work for me: Pomelo 7.0.0 and all EntityFrameworkCore packages 7.0.2

Answer (score 5):

If anyone has faced the same error, in your solution if you have different projects, check if the Microsoft Core version and tools versions are the same, removed them all re-installed the packages, the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

In my case in single project **ASP.Net core .Net 6.0** I solved the issue by Installing **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** version **6.0.14** instead of **7.0.3**

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same issue, all your entityframeworkCore packages should have the same regardless of the version type. Now i installed all latest version now its working