# Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion error

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core

> Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type,
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter,
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer,
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer,
> System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.

I'm getting this error. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 36):

I think this is the same problem that I was seeing, and the solution is described in this question:

[Error while add migration to create database in Entity Framework 6, method not found CoreTypeMappingParameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928549/error-while-add-migration-to-create-database-in-entity-framework-6-method-not-f)

In a nutshell, what worked was making sure all the entity framework packages were the same version (in my case 6.0.10). I had a 7.0.something version sneak into one project and that caused the error.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. I was using MariaDB with net8. I also reported the issue here: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1773

Answer (score 20):

Uninstall 7.0 version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
and then

In NuGet package manager console (PMC), run

PM> `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design -Version 6.0.10`

Comment: So does this mean version 7 isn't compatible with the MySql libraries (yet)? Sounds familiar with every version.

Comment: **Some Times you might need downgrade package to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools(6.0.8)**

Answer (score 18):

I got this error after upgrading a project that was using was using MySQL through EF Core via `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` to .NET 8.

At this time, the current stable version of the Pomelo library is `7.0.0`, but that's not compatible with EF Core 8 (triggering this error). The solution was to enable prerelease packages and upgrade to `8.0.0-beta.2` (or whichever the latest version is at the time you read this).

Comment: I updated to 8.0.0-beta.2 and it worked!

Comment: Check the Pomelo compatibility table here: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?tab=readme-ov-file#compatibility

Comment: The new stable version Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql Version="8.0.2" worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Making sure all the Entity Frameworks are the same version should fix the problem. Worked for me on VS2022 version 17.2.12.

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem in the following way:

- I installed the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
- And I added `;Trust Server Certificate=true` in my connection string

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for adding an answer similar at the core but I didn't know how to just "uninstall" nor where the PMC PM> prompt is, so I'm attempting a more complete answer:

---

My problem came from setting up a .NET 6 (LTS) solution/project in VS22 community (tool noob here) but following instructions of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#installing-the-tools that installs the latest rather than a version compatible with solution dependencies

```bash
# dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design # note there's no version
```

---

Solving it using the [`dotnet` cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/) (in powershell as it were):

```bash
  dotnet list package # to see version of packages like Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer or Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
# dotnet remove package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design # if missmatching version installed
  dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version 6.0.15 # note my specific version from the first step and that I'm not using --global
```

Of course the `add` by version from `list` would be scriptable, in powershell eg:

```
  dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design --version $($id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' ; dotnet list package|? {$_ -match $id}|% {$_ -replace ('^\s*>\s*'+$id+'\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*$'),'$1'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue after an update to .net v8.  I have a dll that is just scaffolded from a MySQL database with the project file (.csproj) of

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <!-- <EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures> -->
    <GenerateRequiresPreviewFeaturesAttribute>False</GenerateRequiresPreviewFeaturesAttribute>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.10">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For this example the above is saved in a file ProjectName.csproj and a copy in a file named ProjectName.csproj.build

I created a new project file to perform the scaffolding

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.8">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.16" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This file is saved as ProjectName.csproj.scaffold

Then use the following script to re-scaffold

```
del ProjectName.csproj
cp ./ProjectName.csproj.scaffold ./ProjectName.csproj
rm ContextObjectsFolder
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=localhost;Database=DBName;User Id=DBUser;Password=DBPassword;" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o    ContextObjectsFolder --no-pluralize -f --no-onconfiguring --context    ContextObjectName
del ProjectName.csproj
cp ./ProjectName.csproj.build ./ProjectName.csproj
```

Replace DBName with your database name

Replace DBUser with your MySQL user name

Replace DBPassword with your MySQL password

Replace ContextObjectsFolder with the folder you want your EF objects in

Replace ContextObjectName with the DB context name you want to use

You will need to do a few clean ups to resolve warnings, but you should be able to use it in your application.

Add the following reference to your application(s) that reference the DLL

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.10">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

And now you should be good to use MySQL EF in your .Net 8 application.

Answer (score -2):

Please add the following in the connection string

```
;Trust Server Certificate=true
```

reference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/certificate-chain-not-trusted?tabs=ole-db-driver-19

Comment: An error occurred in DataServices => MySql.Data
Message Option not supported. (Parameter 'trust server certificate')
StackTrace:    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(String key)
         at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)