# EF Core 8 Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Trying to update a project to .NET 8.0. I updated all the related packages to match the 8.0 version.

But it throws `System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor` at runtime.

I tried to check the migrations in cli but most of the commands give me this:

```
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Method not found: ...
```

`dotnet ef dbcontext list` does recognize my context but it always throws the error.

I am using mysql. The packages related and their versions are :

- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.0-preview
- MySql.Data 8.2.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 8.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 8.0.0
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers 8.0.0

My project works well on the 7.0 version. I did not modify anything except updating the packages in this new 8.0 branch.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74362630/method-not-found-void-coretypemappingparameters-ctorsystem-type-microsoft-e)

Comment: You probably have another EF Core library which is the wrong version. If not, uninstall everything and reinstall. They all need to be 8+. You get to be one of the lucky 392 people so far downloaded MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.0-preview.....

Comment: @Charlieface I double checked the packages. The ef packages should be good. Maybe there is something wrong with the mysql efcore preview...

Comment: I wouldn't use a Preview package.  Too many times I find there are bugs in Preview versions.

Comment: @jdweng The preview version seems to be the only version compatible with .NET 8 and EF Core 8 for now. That's the only reason why I use it. It's worse than a bug. I almost can't get anything up and running.

Comment: ´dotnet ef ´ updated?

Comment: Make sure you are using the daily updates : https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/tree/main#daily-builds

Comment: did you update target framework version of the project itself too?

Comment: The latest version was released two days ago.  Here are some of the issues : https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues

Comment: @EmreBener I did

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I can confirm I'm using dotnet ef command line tools 8.0

Comment: Try Pomelo driver. Oracle's driver may have issues, as usual.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv just tried Pomelo 8.0.0 beta2. The only line I modified is the `UseMySql`. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

There might have been something wrong with [MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.0-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.EntityFrameworkCore/8.0.0-preview)

For now the only way to solve this should be switching to  [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/8.0.0-beta.2).

If your code works fine on the older version of .NET, the only line you need to change is where you call `UseMySql`.

Answer (score 1):

For .Net 8 Please use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql version 8 and above.

Comment: I encountered the same error, 
Install Pomelo's MySQL database provider for Entity Framework Core. 8.0.0-beta.2
can fix it, 

but MySQL Server database provider for Entity Framework Core. 8.0.0-preview+MySQL8.2.0 , still error

thank you !!!

(then waiting official version )