# After Upgrading the dotnet from v2 to v8, i am getting this error - System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, nuget-package

I am using C# in my backend and Angular in frontend and after upgrading dotnet to version 8 I am getting this error while trying to login through frontend -
 `` System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void CoreTypeMappingParameters..ctor(System.Type, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ValueComparer, System.Func`3<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IProperty,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType,Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ValueGeneration.ValueGenerator>)'.' ``

Here in the return function I am getting this error-

```
public LoginResponce ValidateUserLogin(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    MySqlParameter[] sqlParams = new MySqlParameter[1];
    sqlParams[0] = new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = "loginId", MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar, Value = loginRequest.UserId.StringVal() };

    //return Context.Query<LoginResponce>().FromSql("Call ValidateUserLogin (@loginId)", sqlParams).FirstOrDefault();

    return Context.LoginResponces.FromSqlRaw<LoginResponce>("Call ValidateUserLogin (@loginId)", sqlParams).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here is the code for connecting with the database string -

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Log(CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning));

    if (optionsBuilder.IsConfigured == false)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(EntityConstants.SQLConnectionString, new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 33)))
        .UseLazyLoadingProxies(false) // <-- enable Lazy Loading
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .EnableDetailedErrors();
    }
}
```

I have tried the following things

1. I added 'TrustServerCertificate=True' to my database connection string.
2. Check that all versions are compatible with EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while add migration to create database in Entity Framework 6, method not found CoreTypeMappingParameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72928549/error-while-add-migration-to-create-database-in-entity-framework-6-method-not-f)

Comment: Have you also updated all NuGet packages to the latest version?

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan, After upgrading the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql to the latest versions, it's resolved.

Comment: @AbhishekNegi Great! I'll post it as an answer so you can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NuGet Packages aren't automatically updated when you change the .NET version, you have to do that manually. Usually EF Core / dotnet contains too much breaking changes to keep all versions compatible with each other.

In this case, EF Core tries to call some method which isn't available anymore in .NET 8 but was in the version the package is built with, hence the `MissingMethodException`.